# rake db:migrate fails with globalize gem and rails 4.1.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, pg, globalize

I'm trying to use the globalize gem with Rails 4.1.7.
Using latest RVM version, os is Ubuntu 12.04, db is postgresql 9.3.

Following the instructions found in readme.md on github i added the translates directive in my model and scaffolded a migration

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
    translates :name, :description
end

class CreateIngredientTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Ingredient.create.translation_table!({
        name: :string,
        descripion: :text
        }, {
          migrate_data: true
        })
  end
  def down
    Ingredient.drop_translation_table! migrate_data: true
  end
end
```

Then when i do rake db:migrate i get the following error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "ingredient_translations" does not exsist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"ingredient_translations"...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"ingredient_translations"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/home/kranz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@recipes/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec'
```

This is really weird.
Googling around for this kind of error I found a ticket in github 
https://github.com/globalize/globalize/issues/288
opened in Dec 2013 and still not closed which seems very similar; the only solution seems to be a hack in globalize code, but i'd prefer not to monkey patching code at that level.
Is it due to the combination of postgres and globalize or there is any other solution to this?

Comment: Fix wrong migration, such as: `Ingredient.create_translation_table!`